# Which browsers support a http 303 response?

Tags: http, browser

After reading about redirects, it seems in the majority of cases I should use a 303 [see here](http://softwareas.com/the-weirdness-of-ajax-redirects-some-workarounds).  So I was wondering if all browsers will support a 303 response, for both normal requests and ajax requests?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. 303 has different semantics compared to 301, 302, and 307.

Comment: right. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_307#3xx_Redirection for a list of possible options.

Answer (score 13):

[303 See Other](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) was standardized as part of [HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) which was released
in 1999. Essentially all browsers still in use support *HTTP/1.1*.

Common browsers:

- Chrome (all versions)
- Firefox (all versions)
- IE 4+
- Opera 4+
- Safari (all versions)

Other browsers:

- Lynx 2.6+
- Mozilla 0.9.4+
- Netscape 6.2+

### References

#### Chrome

According to [HTTP Methods and Redirect Status Codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx), Chrome 13+ supports
*303 See Other*.

Due to [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) being released in
2008 and using [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) (originally), it almost definitely has always supported *HTTP/1.1*. NOTE: This is an
unsubstantiated claim, but I cannot find anything to the contrary.

#### Firefox

According to [HTTP Methods and Redirect Status Codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx), Firefox 6+ supports
*303 See Other*.

[Which browsers can handle Content-Encoding: gzip](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm#Mozilla)
(found by [David Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/535070/369450)) indicates *HTTP/1.1* is supported by Netscape 6.2+
(Mozilla 0.9.4+) which is the precursor to all Firefox versions.

#### Internet Explorer

According to [HTTP Methods and Redirect Status Codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx), IE 6+ supports *303 See Other*.

[Django #13277](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13277) (mentioned by [oDDsKooL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759182/which-browsers-support-a-http-303-response/8759224#comment15429205_8759224)) claims IE 4+ is supported, but
IE 5-6 have buggy implementations. Upon futher reading, is appears that IE 6
redirection works fine, but displaying a custom error message is buggy.

- [HTTP 303 and IE](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-sweo-ig/2008Jan/0053.html)
- [How IE responses to different HTTP status codes](https://web.archive.org/web/20090429081951/http://blog.jamtronix.com/2006/03/how_ie_handles_with_http_statu.html)
- [How IE Handles HTTP Status Codes](https://web.archive.org/web/20100724222329/http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2006/03/15/109.aspx)
- [Description of Hypertext Transport Protocol Error Messages](https://web.archive.org/web/20090916075934/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218155)

[Which browsers can handle Content-Encoding: gzip](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm#Microsoft)
(found by [David Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/535070/369450)) indicates IE 4+ supports *HTTP/1.1*.

#### Opera

According to [HTTP Methods and Redirect Status Codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx), Opera 11.5+ supports
*303 See Other*.

[Which browsers can handle Content-Encoding: gzip](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm#Opera-old)
(found by [David Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/535070/369450)) indicates Opera 4+ supports *HTTP/1.1*.

#### Safari

According to [HTTP Methods and Redirect Status Codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx), Safari 5.1+ supports
*303 See Other*.

Due to [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) using
[WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) which was forked from
[KHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KHTML) in 2001, I assume Safari has
always supported *HTTP/1.1*. NOTE: This is an unsubstantiated claim, but I
cannot find anything to the contrary.

Answer (score -7):

All browsers support 303 redirection, it is a HTTP standard and all browsers identify 303 redirection.

But I would not recommend to use 303 redirection(generally used for old CGI scripts responses), since it is not identified by Search Engines

302 is temporary redirection. and we should avoid it.

You should always use 301 redirection(Moved Permanently)

Comment: 303 should be used when you do a PRG pattern (see wikipedia), that is when you do a POST and then want to redirect user to a GET page so he won't do a second POST by accident when refreshing the page.

Comment: "All browsers support 303 redirection" : this statement seems a bit too optimistic ? what about old versions of IE for instance ? what about mobile browsers ?

Comment: this django page suggests IE6/7 have bugs in their implementation of 303: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13277

Comment: "You should always use 301" is an atrociously inaccurate statement. It's the last thing you want in response to a POST request, or in any other case where the redirected URL should not be cached by browsers and proxies.