# Do modern browsers cache ajax responses?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, browser-cache, cache-control

I have recently found that we use `Cache-Control:no-cache` in all the WebApi responses. I know that before browsers caching did vary a lot and you never knew if the browser can cache you json, so it was important.

As far as I remember now, no modern browser is caching ajax responses so this header is not needed. But I would really like to double check and ask here about the behavior, since could not found any recent posts on the topic.

So the question really is: Do we still need to set `Cache-Control:no-cache` for web api calls from SPA application and if yes, then which browsers do the caching?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't the browser just use its cache from prior ajax calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230998/cant-the-browser-just-use-its-cache-from-prior-ajax-calls)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, since the other question is actually 8 years old and a lot has changed since, that's why I included "modern" in the title. I have read that one before posting here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [HTTP/1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-2) browser HTTP cache key is a combination of a request HTTP method and URI. Browser doesn't take into consideration how request was made:

> The primary cache key consists of the request method and target
> URI.    However, since HTTP caches in common use today are typically
> limited    to caching responses to GET, many caches simply decline
> other methods    and use only the URI as the primary cache key.

So if requests that you perform are cacheble you still need that header value. Check [HTTP Caching MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) and [Which webbrowsers use http/1.1 by default? question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535053/which-webbrowsers-use-http-1-1-by-default) for more details.

Also you may need to add another headers for IE specifically. Check [Make IE to cache resources but always revalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017454/make-ie-to-cache-resources-but-always-revalidate) question for more information.